# Picture in spannable edittext display twice

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I have a review system which allows to add text and upload picture via imgur. 
When I display the review, the pic displays twice, I don't understant why.

here is the part of the code:

```
public class ReviewListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ....
        ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
          ...

    if (text != null) {

        int begin = text.indexOf("[img]");
        int end = text.indexOf("[/img]");
        if (begin != -1 && end!=-1 && begin<end) {
            String imgUrl = text.subSequence(begin + 5, end).toString();
            imgUrl = imgUrl.substring(0,imgUrl.length()-4)+"m"+imgUrl.substring(imgUrl.length()-4, imgUrl.length());
            Log.e("IMG", imgUrl); // imgUrl == http://i.imgur.com/AL4Em6cm.jpg

            startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
            new GetImage().execute(imgUrl);
            try {
                startSignal.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // We should have the picture in the Drawable : myPicture
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

            Bitmap pic = Utils.drawableToBitmap(myPicture);
            ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(pic), begin, end + 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            holder.textView.setText(ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }else{
            holder.textView.setText(text);
        }


    }
```

I also put the Private class GetImage ( Inside the same file)

```
private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        URL url;
        boolean isPicture = false;

        try {
            if (!params[0].equals(""))
                isPicture = true;

            if (isPicture)
                url = new URL(params[0]);
            else
                url = new URL(icon);

            Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            if (isPicture)
                myPicture = new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), mIcon1);
            else
                myIcon = new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), mIcon1);

            startSignal.countDown();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My list layout (list_item.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
             android:contentDescription="thumb"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/author_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/author_name"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My picture are inserted in the textview as spannable content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem as yours.  The ImageSpan is shown twice at certain condition. [Here is the link to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739748/why-does-android-imagespan-show-my-picture-twice-when-setbounds-exceed-certain).  I found out if the setBound is wider than a certain width, the picture is shown twice.  Although your code doesn't involve setBound calls.

Answer (score 0):

Old question and a niche API, but for anyone else that happens upon it: this strange behaviour can be worked around completely by only using an end range of `start+1`, then deleting the span for the rest of the text:

```
span.setSpan(ImageSpan(context, drawable), start, start+1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
span.delete(start+1, end)
```